# Returning same variable to every controller in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-controller

I need to send the same result to almost every `view` page, so I need to bind the `variables` and return with every controller.

My sample code

```
public function index()
{
    $drcategory = DoctorCategory::orderBy('speciality', 'asc')->get();
    $locations = Location::get();

    return view('visitor.index', compact('drcategory','locations'));
}

public function contact()
{
    $drcategory = DoctorCategory::orderBy('speciality', 'asc')->get();
    $locations = Location::get();

    return view('visitor.contact', compact('drcategory','locations'));
}
```

But as you see, I need to write same code over and over again. How can I write it **once** and include it any **function** whenever I need?

I thought about using a **constructor**, but I cannot figure out how I can implement this.

Comment: Have you thought about creating a `trait` which you can add the functionality above when needed?

Comment: One of a simple way is: add value to variables named `$this->data["drcategory"]` and `$this->data["locations"]`,  in your construction, before return to view, you can write like this `$data = $this->data;` and `return view('visitor.contact', compact('data'));`. You can add more variable into `data` array.

Comment: do you want to share this variable with evey view (handles by other controllers) or juts the views handles by this controller?

Comment: I want to share this variable to views of only this controller.

Answer (score 5):

You are able to achieve this by using the `View::share()` function within the `AppServicerProvider`:

**App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php:**

```
public function __construct()
{
   use View::Share('variableName', $variableValue );
}
```

Then, within your controller, you call your `view` as normal:

```
public function myTestAction()
{
    return view('view.name.here');
}
```

Now you can call your variable within the view:

```
<p>{{ variableName }}</p>
```

You can read more in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#sharing-data-with-all-views).

Comment: Please explain what `View::share()` does and how it will solve the issue.

Comment: I mean you should explain this to the person answering the question. I didn't ask it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to implement this.

You can go with a `service`, a `provider` or, like you said, within the `constructor`.

I am guessing you will share this between more parts of your code, not just this `controller` and for such, I would do a `service` with static calls if the code is that short and focused.

If you are absolutely sure it is only a special case for this `controller` then you can do:

```
class YourController 
{

    protected $drcategory;

    public function __construct() 
    {

       $this->drcategory = DoctorCategory::orderBy('speciality', 'asc')->get();

    }

   // Your other functions here

}
```

In the end, I would still put your query under a  Service or Provider and pass that to the controller instead of having it directly there. Maybe something extra to explore? :)

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can use **View Composer Binding** feature of laravel

add this is in boot function of **AppServiceProvider**

```
    View::composer('*', function ($view) {
                $view->with('drcategory', DoctorCategory::orderBy('speciality', 'asc')->get());
                $view->with('locations', Location::get());
            }); //please import class...
```

when you visit on every page you can access **drcategory**  and **location** object every time
and no need to send **drcategory** and **location** form every controller to view.

Edit your controller method

```
public function index()
{
    return view('visitor.index');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sunil mentioned way View Composer Binding is the best way to achieve this.